# How to whitelist a third-party system without using IP address in DLB in mule 4?

Tags: load-balancing, mule4

I need to whitelist the third-party system to consume mule 4 api. The have peculiar behavior of having dynamic IP address so suggested to whitelist with DNS name (abc.com).

how can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 0):

DLB whitelisting only support IP ranges specified in CIDR format. You could create an application that queries regularly the IP for that DNS address and updates the whitelist using [CloudHub's REST API](https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/portals/anypoint-platform/f1e97bc6-315a-4490-82a7-23abe036327a.anypoint-platform/cloudhub-api/minor/1.0/console/method/%234240/) or executing [Anypoint CLI](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/anypoint-platform-cli-commands#cloudhub-load-balancer-whitelist-add).